# Calculating size of area where data values exceed certain limit

Tags: python, area, basemap, matplotlib, arctic

I am using Python and [Basemap](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/) to plot sea ice concentration within the Arctic region. I need to calculate the total area (square meters) where the sea ice concentration exceeds a certain limit (e.g. 15%), but I am unsure as how to do that.

[image: Sea ice concentration in the Arctic (%)]

My code for plotting the map is:

```py
levels = np.arange(np.min(mydata), np.max(mydata),5)
mymap = Basemap(projection='npstere', lon_0=0, boundinglat=65)
x, y = mymap(lon, lat)

CS1 = mymap.contourf(x, y,
                     mydata,levels,
                     cmap=mpl_util.LevelColormap(levels, cmap=cm.RdBu_r),
                     extend='max',
                     antialiased=False)

mymap.drawparallels(np.arange(-90.,120.,15.),labels=[1,0,0,0]) # draw parallels
mymap.drawmeridians(np.arange(0.,420.,30.),labels=[0,1,0,1]) # draw meridians
mymap.drawcoastlines()
mymap.drawcountries()
mymap.fillcontinents(color='grey')
```

My guess is that I need to convert the contours to polygons and then calculate the areas.

Comment: stereographic (npstere) is a conformal projection. It maintains shape/angles, not areas. You would want to switch to Lambert azimuthal equal area to calculate the areas.

Comment: Thanks. Would you have any suggestions as to how the calculation could be done after switching projection?

Comment: I would calculate a focal percent cover using a X ha moving analysis window.  Once you have a continuous raster dataset showing percent cover, reclassify your raster to 0 = 0-15% cover and 1 = >15% cover.  Finally, count the "1" pixels, which will give the the total area in map units.